# PowerBi get values in rows to columns with powerquery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hi i have a data table

[image: Employee Questian Answer 1 1 Ja 1 2 Ja 1 3 Nej]

Can i make this in powerquery, i dont understand how to make this with the normalization.

[image: Employee 1 2 3 1 Ja Ja nej]

I have better name for questian but this it enoth for my questian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click select Questian column

File ... Pivot Column ...  
ValuesColumn:Answer
    AggregateValueFunction:Don't Aggregate

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Questian", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Questian", type text}}, "en-US")[Questian]), "Questian", "Answer")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/office/pivotkolumner-power-query-abc9c8da-3be9-44c4-886e-0be331ab387a?ui=sv-se&rs=sv-se&ad=se